# R: Statistical significance test for data with non-normal distribution and autocorrelation

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test, autocorrelation, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am testing the applicability of one futures pricing model. As part of the analysis I am calculating differences between actual prices and the prices suggested by the model. After calculating this "mispricing series" and providing basic summary statistics, I would like to test the statistical significance. However, I have encountered two problems.

First, the mispricing series does not follow normal distribution. This means I cannot use classical one-sample t-test to test the null hypothesis that the m. series is not different from zero. Therefore, I was thinking about applying non-parametric test - Wilcoxon signed-rank test as this test does not require the underlying population to be normally distributed.

Secondly, there is quite strong autocorrelation in the mispricing series, which violated the independence assumption of Wilcoxon test.

To correct for autocorrelation I would derive autocorrelation-robust standard errors and would use these in t-test, but this does not solve the problem with non-normal distribution.

May I ask if you have any suggestion on how I should solve the problem? I would appreciate any ideas, I feel quite lost here.

Comment: What are you testing the statistical significance of? That the mean of the residuals is different from zero, and hence your model is unbiased? Also, you can usually appeal to the CLT and not need normality. Depending on what you are doing, have you looked at newey west std errors?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My null hypothesis is that the mean of the m. series is zero which I expect to be rejected. I was thinking about CLT but I do not entirely understand if I could really use it. The sample should be randomly drawn, but I am using the consecutive daily prices, apologies if this is a stupid question, but can I still think of my sample as random?

Comment: ..So just to be sure - If I could really apply CLT, does that mean that even after I reject the normality with e.g. Shapiro-Wilk test in r I can still say that thanks to CLT the non-normality of the original population is not a problem? I have approximately 60 observations per contract and skewness & kurtosis are fluctuating within -2/+2 ..and Yes, then I would apply newey-west SE

Comment: Being able to apply the CLT requires that the random process has enough finite moments and strong mixing conditions, but the exact underlying distribution doesn't matter. So your setup is ... you have K futures contracts and about 3 months of trading per contract? and you are trying to regress that price on something else?

Comment: yes, I have 16 contracts to examine, each trading for 3 months, but as trading volume is low in the early months, I use just the nearest to maturity part of the contract (that's why I use only 60 days per contract)..

Comment: ...Regressing the futures price on the determinants of this price is the second part of my analysis. But first, I would like to show the magnitude of the deviation of the futures price from its theoretical counterpart – that’s why I am calculating this mispricing series and want to conduct summary statistics

Comment: Anyway, thanks Igor! I am going to try to get Newey-West SE and complete my analysis.